# Excel Macro: How to change the cell color of a row within a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range from C17:W39. I would like to make the row within the range Grey or White depending on the value in column E. If the volume is Actual, I would like the row to be grey and if the value is guess, I would like the row to be white. I need it so that only the cell color within the range is changed not the entire row. The below code works on the first row but I can't figure out how to make it loop through the rest of the range. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub Color()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set myRange = Range("C17:W17")
        For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value = "ACTUAL" Then myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        If cell.Value = "GUESS" Then myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree with @pnuts. Why not use conditional formatting? You can conditional format the cells with or without using VBA Code.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code like this:

```
Sub Color()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set myRange = Range("E17:E39")
        For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value = "ACTUAL" Then
            Range("C" & cell.Row & ":W" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End If
        If cell.Value = "GUESS" Then
            Range("C" & cell.Row & ":W" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This loops through each cell in range `E17:E39` and formats the cells from column C to W in response to the value found in the E-column.